# How far into the manga did the Kimi ni Todoke anime reach?

Tags: kimi-ni-todoke

Since the Kimi ni Todoke manga is still running, and the anime ended in 2011, it's safe to assume that the anime didn't adapt everything. However, I know that a lot of it was adapted reasonably faithfully, and I'd rather avoid rereading things which were part of the anime.

What manga chapter corresponds to the end of the second season of the anime? Also, are there any story arcs which were omitted from the anime up to that point?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *Kimi ni Todoke* anime starts at Chapter 1 and covers up to (Vol. 7) Chapter 27 or the first season. The second season technically ends at (Vol. 11) Chapter 43 of the manga, since Chapter 44 is a recap from Kazehaya's point of view. Their first date takes place in Chapter 46, but it's a bit different compared to final scene of Kimi ni Todoke 2nd Season.

The anime stays pretty faithful to the manga so nothing major was left out. I believe they ended it here, because there wasn't enough material to adapt to another season. So if you wanted to continue where the 2nd Season left off, you should start with Chapter 44/45.

Comment: There seems to be a general consensus on the internet that nothing major (on the level of chapters or story arcs) was cut out of the anime, so  this answer is probably as complete as it can be.

Comment: Does **both** season restarts from chapter 1? Your wording is confusing.