# Does Sailor Moon Crystal contain the Black Moon arc of the manga (Pluto and Chibiusa)?

Tags: anime-production, sailor-moon

Has it been officially stated anywhere by a representative at the production company whether *Sailor Moon Crystal*'s 26 total episodes cover the Black Moon arc of the manga (Chibiusa, Sailor Pluto, and the Black Moon Clan, equal to season R of the classic anime series)?  Has it been stated anywhere that it only covers the content of the Dark Kingdom arc of the manga (equivalent to the first season of the classic anime)?

*Crystal* has covered in a mere 8 episodes the equivalent of 33 episodes of the classic anime series which contained 46 episodes total.  In other words, it has covered 72% of the classic anime's first season content within only 31% of *Crystal*'s scheduled episode count. I know that *Crystal* is based on the original manga, that it is *not* adapting the classic anime, and that the manga storyline progressed much faster (less filler), but even so, that's a big percentage of the manga's Dark Moon arc to have already shown us in only 8 episodes.

The opening animation sequence does not include any characters introduced in the Black Moon arc, but then again, it could receive a new animation sequence mid-run at the point in time when that manga arc would begin (without a second season needing to occur to herald the story arc shift).

Comment: this does sound like Fullmetal Alchemist Brother. in the original 2003 series first meet Marcoh in Episode 14 but in Brotherhood this is in Episode 6, in Botherhood alot of the stuff before Lior and from Lior to Eastern Command is omitted either because it was filler or that we already have seen it (we don't see the Youswell ordeal despite it still being different in the manga and the train incident with Bald did occur in the manga too). if i was to venture a guess i would say that maybe it's the same thing?

Comment: @  Toshinou Kyouko, Jon Lin, senshin, user1306322, Danalog: I am confused about why this was put on hold because I did not ask about "unannounced future events."  I only asked whether or not there has already been an official announcement made which someone could point me to: "Has it been stated anywhere..." It is not likely that this sort of info would be found on "anime news sources" but rather in an Japanese magazine interview or website by the company, which someone could be aware of. It could be that the answer is no, no official answer has thus far been made.

Comment: I have changed the question title to better reflect that I am inquiring about an official announcement that has already been made by this date, rather than about something which is "only known to the creators of said works" and that will not be announced until some point in the future. Also, I am inquiring about the current series which was set officially at 26 total episodes, not about a future anime release such as "Will Bleach air again?"

Comment: I think the revised question title now makes this question useful for people far past the end of the run of the current anime series, in the same way as this questions is useful: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3282/how-far-into-the-manga-did-the-kimi-ni-todoke-anime-reach

Comment: @seijitsu Sorry, I kind of skimmed your question when casting my close vote. I agree that this question should probably be reopened, and cast a reopen vote accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I'm not sure if anything had come up by October, since I haven't really followed Sailor Moon beyond watching the biweekly episodes and I don't know Japanese. But some announcement (referred to [here](http://www.themarysue.com/sailor-moon-crystal-r/)) seems to have been made in early November at an anime convention in Tokyo. The fact that there apparently was speculation before this suggests that no announcement had been made before the anime convention. (I found out about this mostly since I'd read about a newly released trailer, and wanted to find some details about it.)

---

Looking from some recent news sources (e.g [this one](http://www.denofgeek.us/tv/sailor-moon/241109/sailor-moon-crystal-to-adapt-black-moon-arc) from November 8), it seems that the second half of SMC will cover the Black Moon arc.

A [official trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7q-rU8s9HCY) was apparently recently released (December 27), and from [ANN](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-12-27/sailor-moon-crystal-black-moon-arc-trailer-previews-chibi-usa-sailor-pluto/.82667), we have:

> The anime premiered on July 5 and airs on the first and third Saturdays every month. Starting on January 17, the second season includes the story from the original manga's "Black Moon" arc and features Chibi Usa. The Comic Natalie website posted more images from the upcoming episodes.

Initially I was sceptical as to whether this new "season" mentioned in some sources was referring to part of the current SMC or to an altogether new production after this one finishes, but the date given (January 17 next year) implies that it should be within the current production.